# Ursprung von "Und das ist auch gut so"

Tags: etymology

Ist es wahr, dass der Ausdruck "Und das ist auch gut so" von Klaus Wowereit stammt? Er sagt in einem Interview: "*Der Zusatz... "und das ist auch gut so", der dann zu einem **geflügelten Wort** wurde...*"

Oder habe ich etwas falsch verstanden?

Comment: Der Satz wurde mit Sicherheit auch schon vor tausend Jahren gesagt. Die Frage hätte wohl besser explizit sein sollen, ob der Satz durch Klaus Wowereit populär wurde oder ob der Satz nun wirklich als Redewendung durchgeht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Klaus Wowereit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Wowereit) wurde 1953 geboren. Wäre er tatsächlich der Erfinder dieser Redewendung, dann dürfte diese Wendung vor seiner Geburt nicht in der Literatur zu finden sein. Tatsächlich wurde sie aber schon im zweiten Weltkrieg in Bücher gedruckt, wenn auch nicht so häufig wie heute. Das kann man an diesem *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=das%20ist%20auch%20gut%20so&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdas%20ist%20auch%20gut%20so%3B%2Cc0)* recht gut sehen:

[image: das ist auch gut so]

Also:

Frage: *Ist es wahr, dass der Ausdruck "Und das ist auch gut so" von Klaus Wowereit stammt?*
Antwort: **Nein**

Comment: Sehr schlau, danke!

Comment: Die Daten sind geglättet, und das fragliche Aussage war 2001, ist ist also durchaus verträglich mit den Daten, dass sie einen großen Effekt hatte.

Comment: Klaus Wowereit hat den Satz aber erst zu einem geflügelten Wort gemacht.